# Creating parameters to stop from adding to an array?

Tags: java

I have a program that takes in user input for a length and a width and adds it to an array of shapes and after creating and adding each shape it prints them out after each one. BUT, if one of the values are negative (invalid) then it is not supposed to put that shape into the array (which is also not supposed to print into the updated array after each step)

*Here's my output:*

> Enter 1: Add a shape
>
> Enter 2: Remove a shape
>
> Enter 9: Quit
>
> 1
>
> What type of shape?
>
> Rectangle, Triangle, or Circle?
>
> Rectangle
>
> Enter a length followed by a height
>
> 4.0 3.0
>
> Rectangle Length: 4.0 Height: 3.0 Area: 12.0
>
> Enter 1: Add a shape
>
> Enter 2: Remove a shape
>
> Enter 9: Quit
>
> 1
>
> What type of shape?
>
> Rectangle, Triangle, or Circle?
>
> Rectangle
>
> Enter a length followed by a height
>
> -3.0 5.0
>
> Invalid length
>
> **Rectangle Length: 0.0 Height: 5.0 Area: 0.0**
>
> Rectangle Length: 4.0 Height: 3.0 Area: 12.0
>
> Enter 1: Add a shape
>
> Enter 2: Remove a shape
>
> Enter 9: Quit

**That bolded portion is not supposed to be there, that is my problem**

*Here's the ShapeCollection which contains my methods:*

```
    private Shape[] shapes;
private int index;

public ShapeCollection() {
    this.shapes = new Shape[10];
    index = 0;
}

public ShapeCollection(int size) {
    this.shapes = new Shape[size];
    index = 0;
}

//Accessors
public Shape[] getShapes() {
    return shapes;
}

//Mutators
public void setShapes(Shape[] shapes) {
    this.shapes = shapes;
}

//Methods
public void addShape(Shape shape) {
    this.sortShapes();
    if (index > shapes.length - 1) {
        System.out.println("The shape collector is full");
    } else {
        shapes[index] = shape;
        index++;
    }
}

private void sortShapes() {
    for (int i = 0; i < this.shapes.length; i++) {
        int smallestIndex = i;
        for (int j = i; j < this.shapes.length; j++) {
            if (shapes[j] != null && shapes[smallestIndex] != null) {
                if (shapes[j].getArea() < shapes[smallestIndex].getArea()) {
                    smallestIndex = j;
                }
            }
        }
        if (smallestIndex != i) {
            Shape temp = shapes[i];
            shapes[i] = shapes[smallestIndex];
            shapes[smallestIndex] = temp;
        }
    }

}

public void removeShape(String type, double area) {
    this.sortShapes();
    for (int i = 0; i < shapes.length; i++) {
        if (shapes[i].getShapeType().equalsIgnoreCase(type) && shapes[i].getArea() == area) {
            shapes[i] = null;
            index--;
            break;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < shapes.length - 1; i++) {
        if (shapes[i] == null && shapes[i + 1] != null) {
            for (int j = i; j < shapes.length - 1; j++) {
                shapes[j] = shapes[j + 1];
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}

public void printShapes() {
    this.sortShapes();
    for (int i = 0; i < shapes.length; i++) {
        if (shapes[i] != null) {
            System.out.println(shapes[i].getShapeType() + " " + shapes[i].toString() + " Area: " + shapes[i].getArea());
        }
    }
}
```

*Here's the Rectangle class which has the mutators and constructs:*

```
private double length;
private double width;

//Default construct
public Rectangle() {
    this.length = 0.0;
    this.width = 0.0;
}

//Parameterized construct
public Rectangle(double aLength, double aWidth) {
    this.setLength(aLength);
    this.setWidth(aWidth);
}

//Accessors
public double getLength() {
    return this.length;
}

public double getWidth() {
    return this.width;
}

//Mutators
public void setLength(double newLength) {
    if (newLength < 0) {
        System.out.println("Invalid length");
        return;
    }
    this.length = newLength;
}

public void setWidth(double newWidth) {
    if (newWidth < 0) {
        System.out.println("Invalid width");
        return;
    }
    this.width = newWidth;
}

public String getShapeType() {
    return "Rectangle";
}

public double getArea() {
    return (this.getLength() * this.getWidth());
}

public String toString() {
    return "Length: " + this.getLength() + " Height: " + this.getWidth();
}
```

*Here's the front end which you probably don't need to see:*

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean run = true;
    ShapeCollection shapes = new ShapeCollection();

    System.out.println("Welcome to the Shapes collections");

    while (run == true) {

        System.out.println("Enter 1: Add a shape\nEnter 2: Remove a shape\n" +
                "Enter 9: Quit");

        int input = keyboard.nextInt();

        if (input == 1) {
            System.out.println("What type of shape?\nRectangle, Triangle, or Circle?");
            String type = keyboard.next();

            if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("Rectangle")) {
                System.out.println("Enter a length followed by a height");
                double length = keyboard.nextDouble();
                double height = keyboard.nextDouble();
                shapes.addShape(new Rectangle(length, height));
                System.out.println();
                shapes.printShapes();

            } else if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("Triangle")) {
                System.out.println("Enter a base followed by a height");
                double base = keyboard.nextDouble();
                double height = keyboard.nextDouble();
                shapes.addShape(new Triangle(base, height));
                System.out.println();
                shapes.printShapes();

            } else if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("Circle")) {
                System.out.println("Enter a radius");
                double radius = keyboard.nextDouble();
                shapes.addShape(new Circle(radius));
                System.out.println();
                shapes.printShapes();
            } else if (input == 2) {
                System.out.println("Enter the shape type");
                type = keyboard.next();
                System.out.println("Enter an area");
                double area = keyboard.nextDouble();
                shapes.removeShape(type, area);
                System.out.println();
                shapes.printShapes();
                System.out.println();
            } else if (input == 9) {
                run = false;
                System.out.println("Goodbye");
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Invalid input");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: We *definitely* needed to see the front end, since that's how information's getting to the object to begin with.  Thanks for providing it.

Comment: Realistically speaking, you should pare this down; only include the code that is *absolutely* vital to this.  Anything else is extra/excess fluff.

Comment: I apologize @Makoto I am new here just trying to figure out my problems and unsure how to optimize since I am a beginner to Java

Comment: Think about what the default values for `double` are... Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that you create a new shape and after that you are checking if the input is valid. I would suggest you check for validity on the front end.

You could create a method to check:

```
public boolean isValid(double value){
    if (value < 0.0) {
        System.out.println("Invalid Input");
        return false;
    }else {return true;}
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But, would I have to create one of these for every variable type (length, width, base, height, radius)? I'm just trying to think of how to best implement it

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are validating the input within the `Rectangle` constructor. You should validate the input *before* passing it to the   constructor (and not creating the object when failing).

But you could fix this broken design to a less broken one by throwing an Exception instead of just outputting the detected inconsistency.

```
/* BTW: never call public methods from a constructor !!! */
private void setWidth(double newWidth) {
    if (newWidth < 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(newWidth +" is less than 0.0!" );
    }
    this.width = newWidth;
}
```

Of cause you then have to add an `try/catch` block around your `if/else` cascade...

Answer (score -1):

Why do you put wrong shape into array?
Think this way:
You got input data into program
You have to validate data, is it correct or not.
If yes put it into array
If not show error message and do not put it into array.
 That's it.

Where you will validate your data is up to you.
 You can do it in your frontend before calling shapes.addShape
 or inside shapes.addShape 
 and do not increment index if input data wrong.

Comment: Wait, what?  How does this even answer the question?

Comment: I am confused moreso than before

Comment: Read answer over.

Comment: Why to put wrong shape into array? that is a question you have to answer to your self.